# How can I overcome clipping of a view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-linearlayout

I have a `LinearLayout`, which has width that exceeds window size. If I translate it using `setTranslation()` function it shows the view as clipped. Is there a way to show it in a proper way (wholly)?

Answer (score 0):

Set in xml the width of the linearLayout to match_parent.